# Appendix centered in the middle vertically

Tags: horizontal-alignment, appendices

I want to center the word Annexes (english: Appendices) in the middle of the page

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,francais]{babel}
        %annexes
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{Annexes}
\renewcommand{\appendixtocname}{Annexes}
\begin{document}
   \begin{appendices}

      \appendix
      \newpage
      \section*{Annexes}
        ...
  \end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

I got the word but left in the top (look image), I want it in the middle and centered (vertically and horizontally) like in the books
[image]

I need it like this (without filigrane of corse)
[image]

Comment: Why are you using `\appendix` within `appendices` environment?

Comment: actually, I learned that from a tutorial, I didn't knew there are an other package

Comment: Some tutorials on LaTeX are quite rotten ... reading the manual(s) of the used packages helps much more than such tutorials

Comment: the guy in the tutorial had the word centered, I don't know why it doesn't in my document

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}

\usepackage[english,francais]{babel}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\renewcommand{\appendixtocname}{Annexes}
\renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{\vspace*{\fill}\centering Annexes\vspace*{\fill}}

\begin{document}
\begin{appendices}
  \clearpage
  \section{First appendix}
  \blindtext
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: not like that, I found this example but I want it centered also vertically

Comment: I put a photo from the tutorial example

Comment: @HindDev: See the update please!